# Using class files from a jar file that already has the path built

Tags: java, class, jar

I'm a little lost here. We were given a jar file which contained 3 different .class files in it. I successfully built the path to the jar file, but I don't know how to use them. The class files obviously contain methods that can be used, but I've never worked with a jar file before so I don't know *how* to use them. I'm not sure if I have to import them somehow, how to instantiate them or anything. I have searched for tutorials to no avail.

All I'm looking for is some guidance so I can get moving on this project. If it is a case where I have to import them somehow how would I do it? For example, I have WikiEdits.class contained in WikiEdits.jar. The name of my main class is P2. Can someone show me a brief example of how this works?

Comment: are you working with maven? and your ide is eclipse?

Comment: if you are working on `eclipse`, you have to add your `jar` on the Project's build path.

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao and RUI- not working with maven and yes I am using eclipse.
I have added the jar on the Projects build path already. I just don't understand how to implement what is contained in the class file as I code.

Comment: you can try a java decompiler to take a look inside the jar file.for example java decompiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the jar to your classpath, if you are using an IDE.

Then, a java class that uses it would look like something like this:

```
package p2;
import blah.WikiEdits;  //references a class in the jar

public final class P2 {  //(this is a strange name for a class, by the way)
  public static void main(String... args){
     //builds a new object of the given class
     WikiEdits thing = new WikiEdits();
  }
}
```

If you are using the command line, these examples may help:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=243

Comment: I'm assuming blah is the package. Am I right? If so, it says p2.WikiEdits can not be resolved. p2 being my package

Comment: Yes, blah is the package, but of WikiEdits class, not the class where you are coding.

Comment: What would cause it to say it can not be resolved and how can I fix that?

Comment: A problem with the classpath. Double-check that. Post the .classpath file created by Eclipse in your app's root directory, if you wish.

Comment: Eclipse: Project->Build Path->Configure Build Path->Libraries->Add Jar, point to the file.

Comment: Apparently there isn't one. Which means I either didn't so what I thought I did or misunderstood. When I am in eclipse I can see the jar under referenced libraries. Earlier I had built the path to it, but when I look in the root directory I do not see a .classpath. Thank you for your patience by the way you're awesome!

Comment: Sorry while I was typing and such I did not refresh and see your comment with directions. So I followed your instructions but not sure what to do from there. I can see the .classpath file but not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Does it have an entry pointing to your wiki-edits jar file? If so, the import in your P2 class will work.

Comment: "Does it have an entry pointing to your wiki-edits jar file?" I'm not sure what that means. What do you mean by entry?

Comment: The .classpath file should have a line like '<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/junit.jar"/>' that points to the wiki-edits jar file on your system.

Comment: I had to unhide all my files which is why I had no clue what you were talking about before... SORRY! <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/WikiEdits.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".classpath"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>

Comment: Well, it shows a reference to the jar. If the path and file name are correct, and your 'import' statement has the full name of the class, including its package, it will work.

Comment: I was using import p2.WikiEdits; . I'm now realizing p2 probably isn't the right package? If not where can I find the name of the package that the file name is in? You deserve a medal by the way

Comment: Try Eclipse code completion: type 'import WikiEdits', then 'control + spacebar', without moving the cursor;

Answer (score 1):

you need to add WikiEdits.jat to your path project, then import and instanciate the class.

```
import WikiEdits

P2 p = new P2();
p.somemethod();
```

Static class:

```
WikiEdit.someMethod();
```

Comment: Tried this as well as John O's above and it keeps telling me The import WikiEdits cannot be resolved

Comment: take a look at jar file with a decompiler to check the names.

Answer (score 0):

In your java class add the relevant `imports` from the jar. And then from command line, you can compile and run your class using the classes from jar by definining the right classpath:

**Compilation**

on windows:

```
javac -cp .;pathtoyourjar YourClass.java
```

on linux:

```
javac -cp .:pathtoyourjar YourClass.java
```

**Execution**

on windows:

```
java -cp .;pathtoyourjar YourClass
```

on linux:

```
java -cp .:pathtoyourjar YourClass
```

If you are using Eclipse then follow this link to know the steps to add jar to your project:

http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps004g/fall05/assign/final/addlibrary.html

Comment: I'm really new so I'm not sure what you mean by "relevant imports from the jar".

Comment: @Geoff You need to add import statements for the classes that you want to refer in your code and are present in jar file.